# Camera X - Accessing both Front and Back Cameras simultaneously using Camera X API

Tags: android-camera, android-camerax

Trying to preview both cameras (front and back) concurrently using Android X API -

```
 Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview); //Back-Camera
 Camera camera2 = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector2, preview2); //Front-Camera
```

With the above code-snippet, only front camera comes up. If I change the order above, back camera shows up as expected.

Tried acquiring the instances of Camera feature (**cameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this**)) twice, however I found strange observation by mapping one camera per one provider. Upon home press and launching app again, either one of the preview (Back or Front) shows up and there is no pattern found.

Can anyone throw more lights on this? Is it anything to do with the target device i.e. device incompatibility? The target device I am using is OnePlus 5.

Answer (score 1):

CameraX doesn't support opening more than 1 camera at a time, which is why when you attempt to open 2 cameras by calling `ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle()` twice, only the second camera is opened.

`ProcessCameraProvider` provides access to the cameras on the device, and as its name suggests, it has the scope of the process/application, i.e it's a Singleton, once it's initialized, you'll get the same instance with each consequent call to `ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance()`.